# Non-equal Set Divisibility

Tags: number-theory

if $A =\{m,n\}$ and $B = \{p,q,r\}$ such that $A$ is not equal to $B$ as sets. Give me a hint on how to prove that: $(t^m + 1)(t^n +1)$ is not equal to $(t^p +1)(t^q + 1)(t^r +1)$ whereas $m$, $n$, $p$, $q$, $r$, and $t$ are positive integers with $t$ is at least $2$. Thanks.

Comment: $t=2,m=n=p=3,q=r=1$.

Comment: But in general it is hard to prove the claim to be true.

Comment: It is usually hard to prove a claim is true, when it is false. The numbers I gave form a counterexample. The only hint I can give you on how to prove the claim is to first find a proof that $0=1$; the claim follows easily from that.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2^3+1)(2^3+1)=9\cdot9=81=3\cdot3\cdot9=(2^1+1)(2^1+1)(2^3+1)$$ so what you are trying to prove is false. This makes it difficult to give you a hint on how to prove it.

There is a theorem of Bang and Zsigmondy which says that most of the time $t^m+1$ has a prime divisor not shared by any $t^s+1$ with $s\lt r$. If you track down a precise statement of that theorem, you may be able to use it to state and prove a result of the type you are asking about.

EDIT: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem), Zsigmondy's Theorem says  if $a \gt b \gt 0$ are coprime integers, then for any natural number $n \gt 1$ there is a prime number $p$ (called a primitive prime divisor) that divides $a^n-b^n$ and does not divide $a^k-b^k$ for any positive integer $k\lt n$, with the following exceptions:
$a = 2$, $b = 1$, and $n = 6$; or
$a + b$ is a power of two, and $n = 2$.